# ¿Cómo recorro un range de forma invertida? Python

Tags: python

Disculpen necesito ayuda con esto, en este ejercicio tengo que mostrar la tabla de multiplicar de un numero dado por el usuario, pero tengo mostrarla invertida, en vez de 2x1, 2x2, 2x3... seria, 2x10, 2x9, 2x8... Gracias de antemano.

```
numero_tabla = int(input("De que numero desea ver la tabla: "))

for multiplo in range(1, 11):
   print("{} x {} = {}".format(numero_tabla, multiplo, multiplo*numero_tabla))
```

Answer (score 6):

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) te permite usar un paso ("step") negativo, es decir decreciente:

> *range(start, stop[, step])*

Por lo que tranquilamente podrías hacer:

```
for multiplo in range(10, 0, -1):
```

Y no hay que olvidarse de ajustar el comienzo y fin del intervalo.

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma es utilizando [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) recorre el rango de manera inversa

```
numero_tabla = int(input("De que numero desea ver la tabla: "))

for multiplo in reversed(range(1, 11)):
    print("{} x {} = {}".format(numero_tabla, multiplo, multiplo*numero_tabla))
```

Ejemplo (tomando 2 como ejemplo):
https://rextester.com/XAQMV54561